# How to set a cfcookie from a user button press?

Tags: javascript, cookies, coldfusion

Scenario: New website appearance that users can opt-into early to beta test.

Currently I've tried using document.cookie tied into the button press (I can see the cookie in Firebug), but whenever I try to run this:

```
<cfif IsDefined("cookie.myCookie")> 
<cflocation url = "myNewWebsitesLookURL">
</cfif>
```

to try to find it and locate the user to the new page, Coldfusion cannot seem to access or see the cookie created by Javascript. (I also took out the cflocation, and added in alerts to ease the testing).

So now I'm looking for an alternative way to create the cookie, since Coldfusion seems to find the cookies it creates swimmingly. Unfortunately the button cannot be cfinput due to constraints with how we load the opt-in screen into the old layout of the page.

Comment: Welp, suddenly my Coldfusion is finding my document.cookie now. -.- Not sure why it wasn't for an hour.

Comment: How are you setting the cookie?